# Can't scrape information from a pseudo pop up with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

So the problem is the next, I'm trying to scrape a website to automate the work of a friend of mine that is a lawyer, and it went really smooth scraping the website they use until this kind of javascript object pop-up came and ruined it all.

So I'm trying to acces to the date(Fecha) 31/10/2018

```
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
texto_columnas = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="grdOperaciones_Row_0_column3"]/div')
```

And this is the "result" that I get

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="grdOperaciones_Row_0_column3"]/div"}
```

obviously I need to do something to access the data from this pop-up, no window element, but don't know what.

[image]

html page-source and html frame-source in this repository:
https://github.com/NazarenoCavazzon/LawAutomatization

Comment: If URL is public, then pls share with us here. also `<div id="grdOperaciones" class="gridView" data-status="initial"></div>` I could find only this in the repo.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.